# Powershell ignores proxy credentials?

Tags: powershell, api, rest, proxy

I am attempting to use "Invoke-RestMethod" in [Powershell 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-4.0).

The user running the script does not have permission to authenticate at the proxy so I want to manually set different credentials and can't use "DefaultNetworkCredentials".

However, it seems that Powershell is ignoring all the settings I make. I always receive 407 as a response.

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

The proxy supports Kerberos, NTLM and Basic authentication. I tried different formats for the username but I have no success. The proxy setting works in other applications with the same configuration.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$proxy = "http://proxyaddress.domain:8080"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "user@domain", $pass
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://.../' -Headers @{"Cache-Control"="no-cache"} -Proxy $proxy -ProxyCredential $cred
```

(The server has no proxy set and it should only be configured for said script.)

**EDIT:**
The Microsoft Documentation seems to be very confusing. The -Proxy switch is displayed as a feature when viewing the document for v. 4.0.
However, looking at the Powershell 7.0 documentation it is stating that "This feature was added in PowerShell 6.0.0".

So it will definitely not work that way. I tried using System.Net.WebClient proxy instead but also had no success. The original code works perfectly in Powershell 6.0.

Comment: Set it to run as a manual Scheduled Task with the creds you need, the provide the user a simple script to start that task.

Comment: The proxy user has pretty much no other permissions besides proxy permissions so it is not allowed to run Tasks or other operations in the script itself. I just updated the post as there seems to be a mistake in the Documentation  for PS 4.0